# multi-select checkbox implementation

Tags: javascript, checkbox, event-handling

I'm trying to create a checkbox menu that outputs a NEW set of values (for searching a table) EACH time a checkbox menu item is checked OR unchecked.

I can get the table to filter on first checking an item, but not thereafter.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="processes" onchange="searchFunction()">
<label for="cbox1">Processes and Roles </label>
</br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="knowledge" onchange="searchFunction()">
<label for="cbox2">Knowledge and Tools </label>


var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var searchObject = {};

function searchFunction(id) {
    if (document.getElementById('cbox1').checked) {
        searchObject.termOne = "processes";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('cbox2').checked) {
        searchObject.termTwo = "knowledge";
    }
    table.columns(2).search(searchObject.termOne + '|' + searchObject.termTwo, true, false).draw();
};
```

Comment: once the termOne, termTwo are set, they'd remain set unless you reset them. so you need a 'else' clause to set them to "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the case where we are unchecked, it may be easier to always start with empty search params, then add params as needed:

```
function searchFunction(id) {
  var searchParams = {}; //start with empty search params each time
  var cbox1 = document.getElementById('cbox1');
  var cbox2 = document.getElementById('cbox2');

  if (cbox1.checked) {
    searchParams.termOne = "processes";
  }
  if (cbox2.checked) {
    searchParams.termTwo = "knowledge";
  }
  table.columns(2).search(searchParams.termOne + '|' + searchParams.termTwo, true, false).draw();
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, hackerdave! The problem must have been that I had the reset invoked outside searchFunction in my original script. ALSO, for others who might be looking at hackerdave's solution here: searchObject should be searchParams in the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another if statement as below returns all rows in the table when all checkboxes are deselected.

```
function searchFunction(id) {
    var searchParams = {}; //start with empty search params each time
    var cbox1 = document.getElementById('cbox1');
    var cbox2 = document.getElementById('cbox2');
    if (cbox1.checked) {
        searchParams.termOne = "processes";
    }
    if (cbox2.checked) {
        searchParams.termTwo = "knowledge";
    }
    if (cbox1.checked == false && cbox2.checked == false) {
        searchParams.termOne = "processes";
        searchParams.termTwo = "knowledge";
    }
    table.columns(2).search(searchParams.termOne + '|' + searchParams.termTwo, true, false).draw();
};
```